# WebView2 is loosing binding of SourceProperty after the first update

Tags: wpf, binding, webview2

I'm trying to bind the `Source` of a WebView2 control.

Here is my view:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Url}" Width="500"/>
    <wpf:WebView2 x:Name="WebView" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding WebViewUri}"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is my ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _url;
    public string Url
    {
        get => _url;
        set
        {
            _url = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Url));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WebViewUri));
        }
    }

    public Uri WebViewUri => new Uri(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url) ? "about:blank" : Url);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Updating the Url-propery for the first time works as expected, but causes the Source-binding to be lost. So, when updating the Url-property a second time, the WebView doesn't navigate to the new URL.

I checked the binding before and after the first update with `WebView.GetBindingExpression(WebView2.SourceProperty)`.
At first I get the correct binding expression, but after updating the Source for the first time the binding expresson is `null`.

For debugging purposes I tried registering several event. The binding go lost somewhere between the `NavigationStarting` and `NavigationCompleted` events.

Is this a bug in WebView2, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using the current version of WebView2 (1.0.864.35) from nuget.

Comment: `x:Name="WebView"` may indicate that you access the control in code behind. Sure you aren't setting the Source property anywhere there?

Comment: @Clemens I just added the name for debugging. The code is from a new project I created, just to reproduce the problem. Except from the normal boilerplate there is no other code.

Comment: Just in case the Source property is set somewhere else, try a TwoWay Binding to a read/write property.

Comment: @Clemens I already tried that. The breakpoint in the setter was never hit.